# SonarQube snapshot show issue while local snapshot not

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarlint-eclipse

I am using SonarQube to find new issues with my code.
I am using eclipse for my project when i run snapshot in local environment using maven then it's not show me issue in report, but when I run snapshot on SonarQube then it's give me issue in my code.

It's not occur all time but sometime it's give me weird behavior, I am not understand why it's give like this.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: 1) What issue is shown by SonarQube? 2) How do you compare it to the Maven run?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify whether you're using SonarLint for Eclipse or some other procedure to "run snapshot in local environment"

Comment: I am using maven to run snapshot in local environment